# does choosing these: django + smartGWT seems like the good way to go?

Tags: java, python, web-applications

I want to develop web sites rapidly with good looking easy to use components when needed.
I like python and java both (each with its own strengths).
from my small research it looks to me like i would like to use django for the general web sites framework (models, views, some generic apps like login, registration, comments).
and if i need like cool gadgets/components on my web site like some cool select boxes combo boxes etc i will use SmartGWT (assuming its possible to integrate it seamlessly inside my Django frameworked web apps), also i would like to outsource the templates to good html/javascript/photoshop/gimp ui designers...

does this sounds like a good way to go? :)

PS I want to stress out what i'm looking for: rapid development, large community, ready made open sources created with these frameworks (so i can look for examples), framework on top of these - so i have ready made components, easy development, availability to graphic designers so i can tell them design these htmls they bring it back to me and i have VERY easy integration, not falling behind the massive amount of SmartGWT amount of ready made components if django would be enough for me without feeling i miss all SmartGWT components i might choose only it, but i cant ignore the massive amount of components in SmartGWT.

thanks

Comment: That's a "does my web framework look big in this?" kind of question... there's no perfect response because there are so many factors to consider. If there was a perfect answer, everybody would be using it (personally, I'd use Seaside, but that's not suitable for many people). If you really want to develop serious websites rapidly, I'd recommend starting with a simple little example site, and try it out in several different web frameworks so that you'll learn to appreciate their pros and cons. Your "small research" will need to become "big research", though ;-)

Comment: Are you going to use those "cool gadgets" a lot and in every app? If not, then maybe start with something lighter, like [Dojo's widgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/widgets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been developing a Django + GWT site for the last 6 months. The last 6 weeks have been with a designer.

Django and GWT are both excellent ways of working. I'm really impressed with both... but if your key objective is "VERY easy integration", they might not be a good match.

Django's default templating is a bit rubbish compared to [Flexy](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Template_Flexy/), PHPTal or Smarty. Mainly because the templates themselves end up being too cluttered to use in designer friendly tools like Dreamweaver.

GWT can be made to operate like JQuery where it takes stuff out of the DOM, messes with elements and then puts them back in elsewhere. This way of working would be fine with a designer but really you want a designer to style GWT widgets (as they are one of the most powerful features in GWT). Styling widgets then becomes an iterative process of adding hooks (CSS styles etc.) to various types of GWT panel and then trusting the resulting combination of CSS+JS+HTML fits what the designer was expecting!

The main problem is the overlap of CSS, HTML, Django, AJAX and GWT. There are quite a few things that could be legitimately done in more then one place. A designer will need guiding in a iterative/interactive way. It's not like a few years ago when designers could just come back with a load of templates that a coder just sticks a few for loops and variable into.

I've been working in this iterative way for a while now and am slowly improving the separation of roles (designer, css-monkey, userface coder, sys. backend etc.) but I'm finding this separation much harder then it usually is with web-frameworks.

But ... the results are really good and we've produced an app. that is far ahead of PHP+JQuery type sites and will be much easier to scale, white-label....

Comment: do you have any code/tips/documents you are prepared to share in integrating GWT with Django?